# can I make Exim deliver some domain mail to lan ip address instead of MX?

Tags: exim, debian-wheezy

I have two servers, one for web and the other for mail, behind same public IP address.
Mails sent from the webserver to domains hosted in mailserver leave this log and don't reach mailserver:

```
1XDFqd-0003FL-3h == (mail_address) R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host
```

I guess it's because Exim tries to deliver mail to public IP address (from the lan side), can I configure Exim to deliver domains hosted on mailserver to a lan address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `manualroute` router that process messages that satisfy some condition(s).

```
inner_mx:
    driver     = manualroute 
    condition  = +local_domains
    route_data = 10.11.12.13
    no_more
```

Make sure that this router is placed before all the rest routers to prevent usual processing/routing.

Comment: I've found `150_exim4-config_hubbed_hosts` which configures a similar manualroute, so I've created `/etc/exim4/hubbed_hosts` with `domain: ip` thanks for pointing me on right direction!

Comment: Heavily branched trees of includes are look like a maze for me :)